# Subdomains on .io domain

Tags: domain, subdomain, registrar

I am thinking about buying a .io domain.

After reading their rules for domain-registration ([nic.io Rules](http://www.nic.io/rules.html)), I am not sure, if it's allowed to have subdomains on such a domain, because a subdomain is, afaik, a third-level-domain, or is it not? Or isn't the subdomain registered at the registrar?

Comment: Sorry, we can't help with specific web sites/services. Please contact your registrar's help desk. That said, I don't know of any reason why you couldn't have as many levels of subdomains as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite some (ab)uses - *.tv probably being the most notorious - two-letter Top Level Domains are assigned to specific countries. Some registrars are more permissive than others about what may be done within thier two-letter TLDs.

The rules in section 4 of that page reserve gTLD ([generic Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain)) equivalents within the *.io ccTLD ([country code Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain)) for actual residents residents of the British Indian Ocean Territory. Analagous to how *.com.uk generally indicates a business (com) in the United Kingdom (UK), they're saying that *.com.io must be a business in the British Indian Ocean Territory (and all the other gTLD equivalents).

In this context, a sub-domain is not by definition a third level domain. You can define whatever you want for sub-domains or hostnames within the domain they've allocated to your control. The host records you establish determine that.